# Convert Object type to List<T>

Tags: c#, list, object

I have an object which can be of any collection type like IEnumerable or IQueryable or List.
Now i want this object to be converted into type List.
Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this??

Thanks

Comment: Is your variable of type Object?

Answer (score 5):

If you have .net 3.5 and System.Linq:

```
List<NewType> converted =
    myUnknownEnumeration.OfType<NewType>().ToList();
```

You need OfType to do the conversion (you can use `Cast<>()` instead if you want to throw an exception for any of the the wrong type) and ToList converts anything enumerable into a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast your object to IEnumerable(T), then call ToList on it (.NET 3.5 required).